# Form wont submit via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form within a div that I want to submit via another page which will run the query and then return to the first page again all within the div which is in a larger page.

I have put the following javascript at the top of the page:

```
<script name='addactivity'>
    function submitForm() {
        $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'activity_new.php', data:$('#newactivity').serialize(), success: function(response) {
            $('#newactivity').find('.activities').html(response);
        }});

        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

and have placed the form in the div as follows:

```
<form id='newactivity' method="post">
        <b>Activity Number:</b><input type=text name='activitynumber' class='textborder'>   
        <b>Title:</b><input type=text name='activitytitle' class='textborder'>
        <b>Time (mins):</b> <input type=text name='activitytime' class='textborder'>
        <b>Leaders:</b> <input type=text name='leaders' class='textborder'><br>
        <b>Description:</b><textarea name='activitydescription' class='textareaborder'></textarea>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit'></form>
<div id="activities"></div>
```

The submit button does not appear to do anything. It should post the values to activity_new.php which looks like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$input2=$_SESSION[ 'unitid' ];

        $meetingid=$_POST['meetingid'];
        $activitynumber=$_POST['activitynumber'];
        $activitytitle=$_POST['activitytitle'];
        $activitytime=$_POST['activitytime'];
        $leaders=$_POST['leaders'];
        $activitydescription=$_POST['activitydescription'];

include 'connect_db.php'; 

$q1c="INSERT into activities (meetingid, unitid, activitynumber, title, description, time, leaders) VALUES ('$meetingid', '$input2', '$activitytitle', '$activitydescription', '$activitytime', '$leaders')";
$r1c = mysqli_query($dbc,$q1c); 

echo $meetingid;
echo $activitynumber;
echo $activitytitle;

//header("location:editmeeting.php?id=$input2");

?>
```

I currently have the javascript on the main page that contains the divs but have also tried it at the top of the page with the form in. I've also tried these two combinations with the `onsubmit = "return submitForm();"` as `onclick = "return submitForm();"` on the button itself.

Comment: *Um...* check your VALUES. You're entering a string for most of them, rather than the variables from your POST arrays. Plus, you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: i know this is not related to your question but putting spaces between ` = ` is super ugly formatting, please stop doing it. also, sometimes you are using `"`, sometimes `'` and sometimes nothing. it's ugly =(

Comment: Sidenote, you need to remove the `header` call in your php script. That will not do anything useful in an ajax call. And there is no `.activities` element in the `#newactivity` form so you will not see your output where you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the VALUES and sorted the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your code when you click on button it will not fire onsubmit() event .

if you change button type to submit  it will work as you have added `return false` to your function

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

Or use below code .you can use button click event to submit form via `ajax` using `jquery`

HTML

```
<input type='button' value='Submit' id="submit">
```

Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click','#submit',function(){

     $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'activity_new.php', data:$('#newactivity').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#newactivity').find('.activities').html(response);
    }}); 

  });
  });
```

NOTE : from below code in success function . there is no element named `'.activities'` in your form. make sure to use correct selector attribute.

```
 $('#newactivity').find('.activities').html(response);
```

Comment: You might want to add that after fixing this, the next problem will be that there is no `.activities` element in the `#newactivity` form :-)

Comment: @jeroen full form is not added in question .. but as you see without button type submit  submitForm() will not call :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer is good but you can make it more complete. And the closing form tag is also there, after the button, so I would guess we are seeing the whole form.

Comment: @jeroen yes you are rite .. let me update in answer to mark missing field

Comment: The submit button is now firing but it reloads the page that has all the divs.  The script I am using is '<script name='submitform'>
function submitForm() {
 $(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
  
  $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'activity_new.php', data:$('#newactivity').serialize(), success: function(response) {
   $('#newactivity').find('.activities3').html(response);
  }}); 
  
 }); 
</script>' I have removed the header part of the new_activity page and set it to echo what was posted so that I could check it was pulling through but its not appearing.

Comment: You dont need to call this click event in side function . just add code in document ready function

Comment: Also use input type button

Comment: Check my updated answer. Remove onsubmit event from form . make  sure button input type is button not submit and copy update javascript code and add in head tag below jquery lib

Answer (score 0):

Simply change input type:

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
             ^^^^^
```